# The inverse variation

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I had a question in the inverse variation as follow
$$
x^4 y^2 - 14 x^2 y + 49 = 0
$$
then I do that
\begin{align*}
(x^2y - 7 )^2 &= 0 \\[3pt]
x^2y &= 7 \\
y &= \frac{7}{x^2}
\end{align*}

Then it should be
$$
y \propto \frac{7}{x^2} 
$$
or
$$
y \propto \frac{1}{x^2}
$$

Which is the right answer? Please explain.

Comment: In you example, you can find the exact relationship between $x$ and $y$.  The variation is only to show the functional dependence between the two variables, and does not take constants into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct because they mean the same thing (although it's typical to use $1$). When you write
$$
y \propto \frac{1}{x^2}, 
$$
you're saying that
$$
y \text{ is proportional to } \frac{1}{x^2}. 
$$
In other words, there's some constant $k$ such that
$$
y = k \cdot \frac{1}{x^2}.
$$
So, for example if $x$ is scaled by a factor of $10$, making $\frac{1}{x^2}$ scale by a factor of $\frac{1}{100}$, then $y$ also scales by a factor of $\frac{1}{100}$. (This is often called an *inverse square* relationship and shows up a lot in physics.)

On the other hand, writing
$$
y \propto \frac{7}{x^2}, 
$$
you're saying that
$$
y \text{ is proportional to } \frac{7}{x^2}. 
$$
But, this just means that
$$
y = K \cdot \frac{7}{x^2} 
$$
for some constant $K$. Since
$$
K \cdot \frac{7}{x^2} = (7K) \cdot \frac{1}{x^2},
$$
we can see that
$$
y = k \cdot \frac{1}{x^2} 
$$
still holds with the constant $k = 7K$. It doesn't matter what the constant is, just *that it's constant.*